# Google places details API call return NOT_FOUND for an existing autocomplete reference

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have a problem maybe someone had the same issue.

I am calling google places autocomplete api call.

Then i am presenting the user with the results and he can select the place.
Base on the selection i am making places details call and retrieve the details of the place.

My problem is that some cases the details service return NOT_FOUND. the full response looks something like this

```
    {\n   \"debug_info\" : [],\n   \"html_attributions\" : [],\n   \"status\" 
: \"NOT_FOUND\"\n}\n
```

Based on google api documentation, NOT_FOUND for place details is:
NOT_FOUND indicates that the referenced location was not found in the Places database.

But i got this Reference just 1 sec ago from autocomplete service call!

Anyone has the same problem?

Thanks,
Noam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two indexes here, one for the autocomplete suggest and one for the map details. You are seeing the results of the two indexes being updated at different times. If you supply the address in question, I can confirm with the appropriate teams, or you can just wait a couple of days for the indexes to come back into sync.

Comment: Thanks Brett, i can see now that the index has been updated. What i don't understand is what is the best practice to work with google places. The problem is that i am presenting a list of autocomplete response to the user. he then click one and if the index is not updated i am getting an error. is there a way to filter out the autocomplete response that their index is not updated yet in the place details?

Comment: There isn't a cheap way of filtering out entries that aren't in our Places Details index. You would wind up doing Places Details requests for each entry of the drop down list, which will use up your quota.

Comment: Any progress on this issue? This problem happens on my site every couple of days; it is very annoying. How am I to deal with this "out of sync" problem resulting in a NOT_FOUND error?

Comment: The weird thing is that _sometimes_ my placeId (`ChIJFStDCSZyhlQRVd9Ou2WCei8`) returns the details, but sometimes it returns `NOT_FOUND`. Is this due to the detail call hitting different servers, some of which haven't been brought into sync and some of which have?

Comment: The thing to understand about Place API is that it is a search API, backed by a large document corpus. The Place ID is a key that is searched for in that document corpus. Sometimes parts of the corpus go offline, e.g. when rack power supplies fail, or servers are over loaded with queries. At those points in times your query will return `NOT_FOUND`, because the document corpus failed to return a hit on the search term inside the query time limit.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be due to the fact that the business is closed.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place#id-errors

I had a similar issue when using the Find Place endpoint. I would get a successful response and a place_id returned and then calling the Details endpoint would return a NOT_FOUND error.

After adding **business_status** to the fields on my initial request to the FindPlace endpoint would return:

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=gtdc.org&inputtype=textquery&languagecode=en&fields=place_id,business_status&key={{googlePlacesApiKey}}&locationbias=circle:{{radius}}@{{latitude}},{{longitude}}
```

Response:

```
{
    "candidates": [
        {
            "business_status": "CLOSED_PERMANENTLY",
            "place_id": "ChIJ7buuHhrhwogR_eWFgXkNyjY"
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Essentially you just have to ignore any results where the status is **CLOSED_PERMANENTLY** as these will not work on the details endpoint.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any way of returning the **business_status** on the Autocomplete endpoint but might be the same issue you are seeing.